# What will happen if i removed or uninstalled BASH shell?

Tags: linux, bash, shell

What will happen if i removed shell from  the OS
will i still able to install it again
or should i install another one first before remove the previous one?.

Comment: you will need to have *some* shell to interact, and most Linux systems will not boot without at least a `sh` compatible shell, which in case of your system probably is emulated by bash. So, don't uninstall bash.

Comment: Even if you don't want to use Bash as your login (or otherwise interactive) shell, it's a relatively safe bet that some of the software packages you have installed depend on Bash being installed.

Comment: Thank you, That was helpful.

Answer (score 1):

Horrible idea - as @anick noted, a large percentage of your machine booting up needs it.

Your package manager probably won't let you do it, but if you somehow deleted it, while running another shell, you *might* be able to get it back depending on your OS. For example, on Fedora/RedHat `yum` and `dnf` use python, but even then, the RPMs are going to have scriptlets that will fail.